# Question about lower Riemann Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f,g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded functions which are Riemann integrable. I want to show
$$L(f,[a,b])+L(g,[a,b])\leq L(f+g,[a,b]).$$

Now I know that if a function is Riemann integrable, its lower Riemann integral equals its upper Riemann integral. So I did the following:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& L(f,[a,b]+L(g,[a,b]) \\[6pt]
= {} & U(f,[a,b])+L(g,[a,b])\\[6pt]
= {} & \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right) \sum_{j=1}^n \sup(f)_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}\right)+ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\sum_{j=1}^n \inf(g)_{[x_{j-1}, x_j]} \right)\\[6pt]
={} & \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{b-a}{n} \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \sup(f)_{[x_{j-1},x_j]} + \inf(g)_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}\right)\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
On the other hand, we have:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
L(f+g,[a,b])&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{b-a}{n} \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \inf(f+g)_{[x_{j-1},x_{j}]}\right)\right)\\[6pt]
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \inf(f)_{[x_{j-1}, x_{j}]}+\inf(g)_{[x_{j-1},x_j\}} \right) \right)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I do not know how the first equation can be less than or equal to the second. I would think that since you are adding up a bunch of supremums of f in the first, that that would actually be greater than the second because you are only adding up infimums. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: My approach would be: for any subinterval [u,v] of [a,b], let $x$ be the point where $f(x)+g(x)$ is minimum.   Then $f(x) \ge \min f$ over the interval, while $g(x)\ge \min g$ over the interval, so $\min (f+g) \ge \min f + \min g$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg: +1 for comment, but you can replace $\min$ with $\inf$.

Comment: You don't need $f, g$ to be Riemann integrable here, they just need to be bounded.

Comment: This inequality for lower integrals is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1679252/148510).  Note that the inequality shown there by OP is erroneously reversed, but the answer proves the correct inequality as you are showing it.

Comment: @RRL : nice catch, I missed it somehow.